# How use afterInterceptor on Ajax Requests in Grails?

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-controller

When using afterInterceptor in Grails controller I would do it like this

```
def afterInterceptor = [action: trackPageView, only: 'show']


private trackPageView = { model ->
  // so something
}

def show() { 
  def user = User.get(params.id)
  if (request.xhr)
     render view:'show', model: [user: user]
  else 
     [user: user]
}
```

This is working great on non-ajax requests but on Ajax request the model is always [:].

How do I get the user object in trackPageView for Ajax requests?

Answer (score 1):

To support both ajax and non-ajax request, you have to do some [content negotiation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#contentNegotiation) and return the respective response. Here's an example straight from the documentation:

```
import grails.converters.JSON
import grails.converters.XML

class BookController {
  def list() {
    def books = Book.list()

    withFormat {
      html bookList: books
      json { render books as JSON }
      xml { render books as XML }
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**: I'll leave the original answer in place as reference and context. Here's an answer/suggestions to your intended question.

Assuming your non-ajax call is working, and you're able to acquire the user object from the model that's passed into your `trackPageView` closure, can you confirm the following:

- are you calling the exact same url on ajax and non-ajax calls
- are you passing in the same params (e.g. user id) for both ajax/non-ajax calls

If yes to both, then technically you should have a model with a user object inside `trackPageView` since 1) you're calling the same method and 2) passing in the same params from both ajax/non-ajax calls.

Comment: This was not my question. The question is how do I get the model in the afterInterceptor on an ajax request?